# Write bone transform from fcurve animation data

Tags: animation, fcurves

I am trying to write an animation exporter and facing issue to write animation bone curve from fcurve data. And the animation looks stretched and not correct at all. Down here is the code to compute transform matrix of bones at keyframe. I retrieve the location/rotation/scale from the matrix and use it to set keyframe data of animation curve. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

def get_bone_matrix ( armature, action, bone_lists, keyframe ):

```
from mathutils import Matrix
# init identity matrix
m = Matrix ()

for bone in bone_lists:

    curr_pose_mat = armature.bones [ bone ].matrix_local
    curr_parent_pose_inverted_mat = Matrix ()

    if armature.bones [ bone ].parent:
        curr_parent_pose_inverted_mat = armature.bones [ bone ].parent.matrix_local.inverted ()

    l, r, s = fcurves_data ( action.groups [ bone ], keyframe )

    r = r.to_matrix ().to_4x4 ()
    l = l * curr_pose_mat
    #print ( l )

    m = r * ( m * curr_parent_pose_inverted_mat * curr_pose_mat )
    m = Matrix.Translation ( l ) * m

return m
```